# How to have two different Swagger Model with same name?

Tags: rest, documentation, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

I am writing swagger documentation(swagger.json) for my project(which is done and alive). Now i have a problem with modelling my object. 
I have a object called "Listing", Which is used to handle both "applications" and "services" internally.

Now in my definition i want to have two objects, one with applications related fields and one with service related fields . But i want to keep the name listing to both the objects,because in the swagger-ui i want the both of the objects to be displayed as listing(since the APIs are already used by users)

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Schema names must be unique, such as `ApplicationListing` and `ServiceListing`. But you can set the schema `title` to customize the schema name displayed in Swagger UI.

```
definitions:
  ApplicationListing:
    title: Listing
    description: Application listing
    type: object
    ...

  ServiceListing:
    title: Listing
    description: Service listing
    type: object
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With out adding unique named `classes`, you can do this by customizing `schema name` for `swagger documentation`.

`@Schema(name = "ApplicationListing")`

and

`@Schema(name = "ServiceListing")`